# Remove /en/ from URL for default language

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I multi-language site (english by default) :

```
/en/ gets added for english (not ok)

/fr/ gets added for french (ok)
```

I want to get rid of the /en/ from english URLs.

Does anyone know where this is actually added in the code, or a way of removing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with below, I am assuming you don't have front controller or something related.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ /en/ [L]
```

Comment: I added this code, but now the site is not working. I guess i have "front controller or something related"